# Iterator through a table and change one picture & caption at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I've been messing around with code to change one image and the caption at a time. 
Afterwards, it will wait for a couple of seconds then change the next picture and so on.

edit: I redid the solution since (pic+1) wasn't working. The program changes the first image then when it goes to change the next image it throws back an error.

[image: Result]

and then the debugger comes in in internet explorer
[image]

Is there a way I can combine the logic of the 4 if statements into one possible chunk? For example if iter is 1 it will select the same code but target pic1 & link1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>

        //array for pictures
        var pics = new Array("images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg", "images/4.jpg", "images/5.jpg", "images/6.jpg",
            "images/7.jpg", "images/8.jpg", "images/9.jpg", "images/10.jpg", "images/11.jpg", "images/12.jpg", "images/13.jpg",
            "images/14.jpg", "images/15.jpg", "images/16.jpg", "images/17.jpg", "images/18.jpg", "images/19.jpg", "images/20.jpg",
            "images/21.JPG", "images/22.jpg", "images/23.jpg", "images/24.jpg", "images/25.jpg", "images/27.jpg", "images/28.jpg",
            "images/29.jpg", "images/30.jpg", "images/31.jpg", "images/32.jpg", "images/33.jpg", "images/34.jpg", "images/35.jpg",
            "images/36.jpg");


        //Array for labels
        var labels = new Array("Dolly's Doll House", "Austin's Odds & Ends", "TJ's Sandwich Shoppe ", "Joey's Collectable Posters ", "Tom's Junk Trunk", "Treasure's Bottles",
            "Earthenware Containers", "Paul's Pottery", "Kelly's Coffee Collectables", "Barry's Bottles", "Belinda's Beads", "Saturday Nite at the Flea!", "Tollie's T-Shirts",
            "TJ's Patrons", "Polly's Pictures", "Dolly's Doll House", "Carl's Collectable Caps", "Central's Backyard Scene", "Callie's Coats", "Coffee at TJ's!",
            "Jennifer's Junk Stuff", "My Secret Flea Market", "Flea's Front Yard", "Old No. 9", "Jackies Junk Shoppe", "Quapaw Gourds", "Hallie's Handbags",
            "Happy Patrons at the Flea!", "UCA Students Cheer Us!", "Opening Up the Flea Market", "Young Patron", "Native American Wares", "Billy's Musical Instruments",
            "Tollie's Tools", "Marie's Shop", "Candy Land Games and Toys");

        // old value for changing all 4 at the same time
        var c = 0;

        var iter = 0;
        var x;
        var y;

        //time
        var timer = 0;

        function setPics() {
            //Set pic
            x = document.getElementById("pic0").src = pics[c];
            //document.getElementById("pic1").src = pics[c + 1];
            //document.getElementById("pic2").src = pics[c + 2];
            //document.getElementById("pic3").src = pics[c + 3];

            //Set labels
            y = document.getElementById("link0").innerHTML = labels[c];
            //document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML = labels[c + 1];
            //document.getElementById("link2").innerHTML = labels[c + 2];
            //document.getElementById("link3").innerHTML = labels[c + 3];

            // shift array to 5
            c = 5;


            timer = setTimeout("changePic()", 4000);
        }


        function changePic() {
            if (c >= 36) {
                c = 0;
                setPics();
            }

            // change element 1
            if (iter == 0) {
                x = document.getElementById("pic0").src = pics[c];
                y = document.getElementById("link0").innerHTML = labels[c];
            }

            // change element 2
            if (iter == 1) {
                x = document.getElementById("pic1").src = pics[c];
                y = document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML = labels[c];
            }

            // change element 3
            if (iter == 2) {
                x = document.getElementById("pic2").src = pics[c];
                y = document.getElementById("link2").innerHTML = labels[c];
            }

            // change element 4
            if (iter == 3) {
                x = document.getElementById("pic3").src = pics[c];
                y = document.getElementById("link3").innerHTML = labels[c];
            }

            // restart to element 1
            if (iter >= 3) {
                iter = 0;
            }

            c++;
            iter++;
            timer = setTimeout("changePic()", 4000);
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setPics()">

    <table class="items" align="center" width="10%" border="0px" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>       
            <td align="left">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" id="pic0"  border="0"/>
                <br />
                <span class="imgTitle" id ="link0">Dolly's Doll House</span>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <img src="images/2.jpg" id="pic2"  border="0"/>
                <br />
                <span class="imgTitle" id="link2">Austins Odds and Ends</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
               <img src="images/3.jpg" id="pic3" />
               <br />
               <span class="imgTitle" id="link3">TJ's Sandwich </span>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <img src="images/4.jpg" id="pic4" />
                <br />
                <span class="imgTitle" id="link4">Joey's Collectible Posters</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate through/reference the table's rows or cells. Just reference the IDs of the images and captions, since the IDs are numbered in your case:

```
for (var i = 0, i < pics.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("pic" + i).src = pics[i];
    document.getElementById("link" + i).innerHTML = labels[i];    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's giving me an error because of the ("pic" + i). Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Nithroel Looks like I copied your `document.getElementbyId()`...there's a lowercase b in there when it should be capital. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop does not have a condition statement in which it evaluates to continue. Check if the `i` variable is less than the `table.rows.length` property in the first loop, and if `j` is less than the `row.cells.length` property in the second loop.

```
for (var i = 0, row; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  row = table.rows[i];
  for (var j = 0, col; j < row.cells.length ; j++) {
    col = row.cells[j]
    document.getElementbyId("pic" + i).src = pics[i][j];
    document.getElementById("link" + i).innerHTML = labels[i][j];
  }
}
```

Or use a more modern `for...of` loop which makes it less complex to loop through the `HTMLCollection` objects of `table.rows` and `row.cells`.

```
for (let row of table.rows) {
  for (let cell of row.cells) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but now I'm getting "Line: 47
Error: Unable to get property 'rows' of undefined or null reference" trying to debug.

Comment: That error means that you haven't found the `<table>` element that you are looking for. Be sure to select the table first.